# Load asp.net website inside winform C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a(n) (MDI) Windows Form application. It contains two forms. One form (Measured data) controls an engine, another form (laboratory) should show my asp.net web site that has various assignments for the user to do.

How can I show the asp.net default page in that laboratory form? I'm using [awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) to make a browsing window in my laboratory form.

Doing the following

```
webView.LoadURL("file:///D:/school/4e%20jaar/Erasmus/ErasmusProject/Laboratory/deault.aspx");
```

gives an error. Probably because the asp.net site isn't online. but how can I run the site so I can see the default.aspx page?

I have on solution with three projects

ErasmusProject

- ASP.NET website
- SIMOclasses
- SIMOForm

Comment: Doesn't that awesomium have documentation that tells you how to do it? Or do you have specific problems? If so, please extend your question.

Comment: Sounds a bit weird that the **site** is not online when your URL starts with `file://` instead of `http://`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you cannot execute aspx files with file:/// path.
You have to execute on IIS.

So first thing you have to do setup iis if you didnt, create new web site (or use Default Web Site) to execute your aspx files, than change your link file:/// to http://localhost or something.

Comment: Quite right, +1! If he wants to display a test page, I would recommend creating a static html page, and trying to load that directly from the disk. It's the fastest way to test the code he has so far.

Comment: Ok, figured as much. Thanks. I'll give the solution to this but of course, the others that say the same thing are correct as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

The URL you've specified looks like its accessing the raw file via the file system. i.e. `file:///D:/.../default.aspx`.

(You've also misspelt 'default' in your question!)

Can you access that URL from a browser (e.g. IE, Firefox, etc) and see the content you want?  I suspect you can't and that you're missing the webserver that is compiling and serving the .aspx pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should host your website first :

```
WebDev.WebServer /port:9999 /path:"C:\Projects\MyWebSite"
```