# Run ASP.NET project inside a Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

We have a very simple asp.net project that's composed of the following: Home.aspx, web.config, and a few images that *Home.aspx* uses. This webform also connects to a sql server database.

So let's say a client purchases our website app. So we go to their offices and we first install the SQL Server database in a server within their network.

Now, this is where I'm stuck: once we create the database (and configure web.config), we want to hand our client a Windows Application (ie. an EXE) that, when double-clicked, will open a Windows Form with a browser control that will display [Home.aspx].

The issue is that I want to include everything in this Windows executable. All images, [Home.aspx], web.config will be included in this executable. The only reason [Home.aspx] would go *beyond* this Windows Executable is to connect to the sql server database that's in the network. It's as if the Windows Application has everything needed to host this website.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: why not install IIS with the aspx website?

Comment: I cannot install IIS. Also, I don't want them to use their browser. The only way to access our web application is through the Windows Form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430870/load-asp-net-website-inside-winform-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Dude the Only way of doing this is either making your ASP.NET Web application a web API on a host server or making it an API on Local Host. So if you are trying to do it on client's Machine you will be needing IIS Installed over that machine. [Here is](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/run-aspnet-web-api-inside-your-application.aspx) a Complete Guide that how you can Run ASP.NET Web API in your Windows form application. So what you have to do is

1: Make your ASP.NET Web API

2: Make your Windows Form Application

3: Call that API from your Windows Form Application

4: Enjoy

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you need to ship a web server with your WinForms app, such as

http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx

https://cassinidev.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

C# program that shows WebBrowser event handlers

You can also set the Url property to change the current page. As with other controls, the WebBrowser offers event handlers. These trigger when a page is being loaded and when the page is loaded. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the form loads, open this web page.
        webBrowser1.Navigate(" http://localhost/Home.aspx");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set text while the page has not yet loaded.
        this.Text = "Navigating";
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Better use the e parameter to get the url.
        // ... This makes the method more generic and reusable.
        this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + " loaded";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The issue is running the site within the Windows Form. In your example, you assume that IIS is running and it's not.