# Run ASP.NET WebApp in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I'm building a web app with ASP.NET MVC but want to be runnable as a WPF.

Is there any way to do this? Or how to run the Program.cs of the WebApp project together with the WPF project?

Comment: what functionality out the web app do you want to see running on the desktop? You can share classes between these project types so long as no UI is involved or both can call the same web services.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your goals are:

**this here is for wpf to web**

- the problem is WPF is windows only (unless you use community remakes such as [Avalonia](http://avaloniaui.net/) or [Uno](https://platform.uno/) platform a.k.a UWP cross platform remake). However if you want to have it on WPF than you have to check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1cfd7462-feea-47de-a6d2-f83ee99ad2c3/wpf-can-wpf-applications-run-on-a-web-browser?forum=wpf) post here.
- another tool is [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/client)

**if you want run web on wpf**

- in xaml you have to add `<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" />`
- in c# it would be `webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");`

**optional**

- with well structured projects you can make all things with little effort.

example:

separate your logic from your ui (if you havent done it yet) and create a new Web/Wpf project. Next step would be adding your Core/Logic project/library to those "UI" projects and just edit the UI.

- learn what is WASM a.k.a. [Webassembly](https://webassembly.org/)

**ADVICE**

use WASM if you want cross platform apps, it's the "easiest" way of creating one thing for all platforms...

Comment: I just had a chance to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096310/run-asp-net-project-inside-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: The approach would be having the web app running and then run the WPF.